# Different results for $\int {2}/(3x+1)\; dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was reviewing some old calculus notes, when I noticed an odd example of integral of rational functions:

$$ \int \frac{2}{3x+1}\; dx $$

And depending on how it is resolved, it gets diferent values.

The first example is:

$$ \int \frac{2}{3x+1}\; dx = \int \frac{2}{3(x+ \frac{1}{3})}\; dx = \frac{2}{3}\int \frac{1}{x+ \frac{1}{3}}\; dx = \frac{2}{3}ln|x+ \frac{1}{3}| + C $$

The second example is only changes a bit (I did substitution by my own, to show my point of view):

$$ \int \frac{2}{3x+1}\; dx \Rightarrow $$
$$   y = 3x+1 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=3 \Leftrightarrow dx = \frac{dy}{3} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \int \frac{2}{y}\; \frac{dy}{3} = \frac{2}{3}\int \frac{dy}{y}\; = \frac{2}{3}ln|3x+1| + C $$

And this is where it gets confusing, I mean, the same integral having two diferent results.

I tryed to plot both to see if they were equal somehow, but they are clearly not.
What is wrong in this picture?

Thanks for your help.

With the best regards,
Saclyr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\log (3x+1)=\log(x+1/3)+\log3$, so the two functions differ by a constant.  This is absorbed in the integration constant $C$.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks :D
It's still a bit confusing for me, but that may be just me :P

Comment: Checking your answer against a given answer in an integration problem is not a question of whether they are *equal* but merely whether they *differ by a constant*.

Comment: The derivative of $\ln(3x+1)$ is $3/(3x+1)$, which is the same as the derivative of $\ln(x+1/3)$.

Comment: Thanks, now I fully understand the problem :D